# jQuery dialog does not appear on second attempt if using a custom theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery dialog with autoOpen set to false.  The first time I call dialog("open") it works fine.  However, subsequent calls (without a page refresh) do not show the dialog.

This problem apparently started when I switched from using jquery.ui.dialog.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js, and jquery.ui.core.js to a custom theme which bundled all of those into jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js.  I pretty much confirmed that the custom theme was the problem by switching back to my old js files.

My custom theme was far from custom as I took all of the defaults (simply went to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and clicked download).

I am using version 1.4.1 of jQuery.

Any ideas?  I'd like to continue using the themeroller, but may have to punt.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that there is a release candidate for the next version of ui. http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-18rc2/ Maybe there's a fix in there?

Comment: Nothing happens at all? No errors?

Comment: No errors.  I can step through my JavaScript just fine.  I have inspected the HTML elements as well and don't see why the dialog would be hidden.  What I haven't done it try to step through all of the custom jquery ui code because what the themeroller gave me was a minimized version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are possible here:

The first: jQuery 1.4 doesn't play well with jQuery UI 1.7.2 in all cases...namely that [effects that involve widget elements end up destroying them](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5076) (which sounds like your case).  If you say fadeOut a window, etc, it can get destroyed.  The current recommendation is to use **jQuery 1.3.2 with jQuery UI 1.7.2**, and wait for **jQuery UI 1.8 for jQuery 1.4+** ([UI 1.8 is currently in RC2 status](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-18rc2/), should be out any day now)

The second, if the first doesn't apply:  You may want to try and just go download the theme again.  There were some bad zips coming off theme roller, the jQuery infrastructure team took it offline and fixed it, it's now restored.  Depending on when you grabbed your zip, it may have been affected.

[Here's the jQuery UI blog post detailing it](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-download-builderthemeroller-status/)

As a side note, if you cut down just to save on bandwidth, [Google CDN hosts the jQuery UI library as well](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jqueryUI), you can pull it from there.

Comment: Beautiful!  That was it!  I initialized the dialog with "hide: 'slide'".  Once I took that out it fixed it.  I didn't really need that effect.

FYI, I downloaded my theme this past weekend (either 2/20 or 2/21) so the bad Themeroller status which appeared to be on or prior to 2/10 should not have been the issue in my case.  But thanks for the tip!